# tc policing и несколько ip

Tags: linux, tc

Есть сервер на Debian который раздаёт Интернет клиентам. В задачи сервера входит шейпинг и NAT. Из-за того, что есть NAT невозможно делать полноценный шейпинг (NAT на выходном интерфейсе срабатывает раньше и меняет src_ip соответственно не получается отправить пакет в нужный класс tc). Поэтому для входящего трафика делаем шейпинг, а для исходящего приходится использовать полисинг.

Собственно вопрос: 
Как можно используя полисинг задать скорость для нескольких ip к примеру у договора есть 3 ip адреса и нужно сделать так чтобы скорость делилась между этой группой ip адресов. Естественно всё это нужно реализовывать в контексте хеш-таблиц.

Что есть сейчас - небольшой но полноценны кусок конфига ограничивающий трафик на одном ip

```
tc filter add dev eth2 parent 1:0   prio 30 handle 2: protocol ip u32 divisor 256 
tc filter add dev eth2 parent ffff: prio 30 handle 2: protocol ip u32 divisor 256 
tc filter add dev eth2 protocol ip parent 1:0    prio 30 u32 ht 800:: match ip dst 192.168.222.0/24 hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 16 link 2: 
tc filter add dev eth2 protocol ip parent ffff:  prio 30 u32 ht 800:: match ip src 192.168.222.0/24 hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 12 link 2: 
tc filter add dev eth2 parent    1: protocol ip prio 30 u32 ht 2:c7 match ip dst 192.168.222.199 flowid 1:a03 
tc filter add dev eth2 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 30 u32 ht 2:c7 match ip src 192.168.222.199 police rate 4096000 burst 409600b drop flowid ffff: 
tc class add dev eth2 parent 1:1 classid 1:a03 htb rate 4096000
```

Comment: Сдаётся мне что сделать так не получится. Проще забить и пусть для каждого ip договора будет полная скорость тарифа для исходящего трафика

Answer (score 2):

Я бы по такому случаю добавил использование Нетфильтра для маркировки пакетов с последующей обработкой меток в `tc`, либо вообще перенёс всю выборку трафика в Нетфильтр, где для этого на порядок больше возможностей. Логика простая — Нетфильтр вешает метку на всё что захочется, а уже `tc` остаётся только применить правильную политику по метке. Плюс в том, что таким образом можно отловить пакеты на любой стадии обработки (и по любым критериям), в том числе ещё и до НАТа. Минус в том, что это усложнение конфигурации и дополнительная просадка по скорости из-за Нетфильтра.

[Примеры](http://rascal.su/blog/2013/03/09/%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-tc/) [подобной конфигурации](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/LARTC/x2755.html) [можно найти](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/8270189).

Comment: Вопрос давно решен. От полисинга отказались. 

Для ограничения скорости исходящего от клиентов трафика используется виртуальный интерфейс ifb0

 Уже на виртуальном интерфейсе делается шейпинг.

Для ограничения скорости входящего к клиентам трафика используется шейпинг на физическом интерфейсе смотрящем внутрь сети.

Comment: Это тоже вариант, да.